# Weird Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

This bug is probably not reproducible (edit:so I thought). I have a textarea with `onkeyup` and `oninput`, when I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> paste something into the textarea it gets pasted twice and the `oninput` event fires twice. Pasting with mouse context menu works fine though. Then I change the name of `onkeyup` to `onkeyup_` to temporarily avoid that it fires to see what changes, nothing changes. Then I test just to make sure that the `onkeyup_` event isn't firing; `onkeyup_="alert('This shouldn\'t fire')"`. Now when I'm trying to paste text into the textarea instead of getting the text I pasted the text `"This shouldn\'t fire"` shows up in the textarea instead, no alert window is created by the alert, instead it dumps it's argument into the textarea, weird.

When pasting with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> the text is added twice and `oninput` fires twice, when pasting with the mouse context menu the text appears only once. But now comes the weird part, I delete the `onkeyup_` event completely, but it keeps firing even if it's not present in the code anymore! And when I "inspect element" I indeed confirm that the alert code is no longer in the html, but it keeps firing, and it keeps dumping it's argument into the textarea instead of displaying it in an alert window. How can Chrome execute code that's no longer there? Does it keep some kind of copy of an old version, and I've made many changes so far and Chrome gets the new version of the file. And why is alert not working as supposed to?

Edit:
Phew, it was hard to track down (I got a lot of code), but this reproduces the bug on Chrome, but works fine on Firefox:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function f(d){
alert(d.value);
}
</script>
<body>
<textarea name="commentBody" rows="8" cols="50" id="addVideo" oninput="f(this)" placeholder="Placeholder text..." style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 489px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 120px; "></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

So the problem is to alert the value of the field? Why?

Comment: Woah ... now that's a wall of text, if ever I saw one.

Comment: It's more like a brick of text, walls consist of several bricks.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that adding a little bit of structure to your text *might* increase your chances of getting it read and answered.

Comment: Yeah I was just being facetious, anyway on Firefox it works just fine. I guess I'll add some line breaks into the text.

Comment: Complete code samples that let us reproduce the problem would be even better. Structure the question as 1. what you have, 2. what you want to happen, 3. what's happening instead.

Comment: @Inerdial No, it wont reproduce, part of the problem was that it was somehow executing code that was no longer supposed to be there.

Comment: @DudeDawg It's exceedingly unlikely anyone will be able to answer this question in this case.

Comment: Just for clarification: did you actually *reload* the page or did you just manipulate the HTML/DOM in the development code?

Comment: I managed to track down the error and edited the question. I believed that the error was somehow inherently local because it was able to execute code that I had deleted. After reducing the example I see that you get into trouble for "alerting" the value of the textarea.

Comment: Fails on Google Chrome version 17.0.963.79, works as expected on Firefox 11.0 1.0

Comment: @JoachimSauer I reloaded many times with ctrl-r, ctrl-f5 and shift-f5, and now I've even made a tiny example page that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Chromium bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124653